# namespace usage is preventing template instantiation of overload

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, overloading, argument-dependent-lookup

I'm trying to instantiate an overloaded template function in a convoluted way, and I'm finding that it gets instantiated *unless* it's in a namespace. The compilation succeeds either way, but it fails to link if the function isn't instantiated.

I can fix the issue by reordering the program so that the overload is defined before the call, but that's actually what I'm trying to avoid.

I'm guessing this is related to ADL.

I've tried to create a *minimal reproducable example* - if I simplify anything further (eg replace SFyp with a native type) there ceases to be a distinction between namespaced and non-namespaced versions.

---

`SZug<T, A>.zug()` forwards to `baz<T, A>()` which forwards to `foo<T, A>()` (`foo` is overloaded later).

`SFyp` is simply a struct used for `T` (native types don't produce same behavior).

`main()` calls `SZug<T, A>.zug()`

If `foo` (and its overloads) are ***defined in a namespace***, `foo` doesn't instantiate. Otherwise, it does.

---

`ns_used.cpp`

```
// Forwarding chain: SZug.zug() -> baz() -> foo().

namespace ns
    {
        template <typename T1, typename T2>
        void foo(T1 v1, T2 v2); // This is overloaded by SFyp
    }


template <typename T1, typename T2>
void baz(T1 v1, T2 v2)
    { ns::foo(v1, v2); }


template <typename T1>
struct SZug
    {
        template <typename T2>
        void zug(T2 v2)
            {
                T1 v1;
                baz(v1, v2);
            }
    };


// SFyp overload of foo().

struct SFyp{};

namespace ns
    {
        template <typename T2>
        void foo(SFyp fyp, T2 v2)
            {}
    }


// Test.

int main()
    {
        SZug<SFyp> z;
        z.zug(1);
    }
```

`g++ -o ns_used.run ns_used.cpp` fails to link:

`clang++ -o ns_used.run ns_used.cpp` fails to link:

```
in function `void baz<SFyp, int>(SFyp, int)':
ns_used.cpp:(.text._Z3bazI4SFypiEvT_T0_[_Z3bazI4SFypiEvT_T0_]+0xf): undefined reference to `void ns::foo<SFyp, int>(SFyp, int)'
```

---

`ns_unused.cpp`

```
// Forwarding chain: SZug.zug() -> baz() -> foo().

//namespace ns
//  {
        template <typename T1, typename T2>
        void foo(T1 v1, T2 v2); // This is overloaded by SFyp
//  }


template <typename T1, typename T2>
void baz(T1 v1, T2 v2)
    { /*ns::*/foo(v1, v2); }


template <typename T1>
struct SZug
    {
        template <typename T2>
        void zug(T2 v2)
            {
                T1 v1;
                baz(v1, v2);
            }
    };


// SFyp overload of foo().

struct SFyp{};

//namespace ns
//  {
        template <typename T2>
        void foo(SFyp fyp, T2 v2)
            {}
//  }


// Test.

int main()
    {
        SZug<SFyp> z;
        z.zug(1);
    }
```

`g++ -o ns_unused.run ns_unused.cpp` succeeds.

`clang++ -o ns_unused.run ns_unused.cpp` succeeds.

Note: They're identical except for commented-out namespacing.

---

And, as mentioned above, if I put `SFyp` and its `foo` overload before `baz`, it succeeds with or without namespacing.

---

What is the reason for this odd behavior? Is it ADL?

Is there any way to fix this so that my overload is considered when `baz` is looking for a `foo`, while still using namespacing?

Comment: The problem is that in the former you're using `ns::`. The same error will occur if you use `::` for the global namespace in the latter instead of using nothing. [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/uGYiJ7teo)

Comment: The actual problem is that ADL won't happen for qualified name like `ns::foo` or `::foo`. That is why we get the error for both of these case as commented in my comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### TLDR

ADL is for looking up *unqualified function names* like `foo` and not for *qualified function names* like `ns::foo` or `::foo`.

---

> What is the reason for this odd behavior?

The **problem** is that ADL can't happen for qualified names like `ns::foo` or `::foo`. This is the reason if you replace `foo` with `::foo` in your second example, then you'll get the exact same error. [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/WQH86r17U). And you've provided only a *declaration* for the **primary** function template and not a *definition* and moreover you've provided the `foo` overload for `SFyp` after defining `baz` so that qualified lookup can't find that `foo` overload's definition. And as we now know that ADL won't be happening, essentially we get the linker error at the end for the missing *definition* of the primary function template since the qualified lookup only found a declaration and so was not able to instantiate a definition from that declaration. Meaning that only the declaration `template<> void ns::foo<SFyp, int>(SFyp, int)` was instantiated. This is exactly was the linker error says.

On the other hand, for an unqualified name like `foo` the ADL can work. This is why your second example works. Basically, in your 2nd example ADL will be happening so that the linker has the *definition available* and so there will be no error in your 2nd example.

There are 3 ways to solve this. The third way to fix this is simply provide a definition for the primary function template. [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/NYTxphAxd). The other two are given at the end of the answer.

---

This can be seen from [ADL documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl):

> Argument-dependent lookup, also known as ADL, or Koenig lookup [1], is the set of rules **for looking up the *unqualified function names*** in function-call expressions, including implicit function calls to overloaded operators.

(emphasis mine)

This means that since `ns::foo` and `::foo` are *qualified function named*, ADL won't happen here. But if you were to use just the *unqualified function name* `foo` then ADL can work(as you noticed in your 2nd example).

---

The same can be seen from [basic.lookup.argdep](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.lookup.argdep#1) which says:

> **When the postfix-expression in a function call is an unqualified-id**, other namespaces not considered during the usual unqualified lookup may be searched, and in those namespaces, namespace-scope friend function or function template declarations ([class.friend]) not otherwise visible may be found.

(emphasis mine)

This means that since in your first example the postfix expression `ns::foo` is a *qualified-id* so  ADL can't work for that and you get the mentioned error. But in your second example `foo` is an *unqualified-id* so ADL can work here and so your 2nd example works.

---

#### Solutions

There are 2 ways of solving this both of which are shown below:

##### Method 1

Below is the working solution where i've forward declared `SFyp` in the global namespace and also declared the function template `void foo(SFyp fyp, T2 v2)` in the `ns` namespace so that the desired overload is called.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>


struct SFyp;    //I ADDED THIS
namespace ns
    {
        template <typename T1, typename T2>
        void foo(T1 v1, T2 v2); 
      
        template <typename T2>            //I ADDED THIS 
        void foo(SFyp fyp, T2 v2);
    }


template <typename T1, typename T2>
void baz(T1 v1, T2 v2)
    { ns::foo(v1, v2); }


template <typename T1>
struct SZug
    {
        template <typename T2>
        void zug(T2 v2)
            {
                T1 v1;
                baz(v1, v2);
            }
    };


// SFyp overload of foo().

struct SFyp{};

namespace ns
    {
        template <typename T2>
        void foo(SFyp fyp, T2 v2)
            {std::cout <<"desired overload called";} //I ADDED THIS
        
    }


// Test.

int main()
    {
        SZug<SFyp> z;
        z.zug(1);
    }
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/O3mmspTWV)

Output of the modified program is:

```
desired overload called
```

##### Method 2

The second method is to just move the `foo` overload before `baz`'s definition as shown below:

```
namespace ns
    {
        template <typename T1, typename T2>
        void foo(T1 v1, T2 v2); 
    }
//-------------------I MOVED THIS HERE-----------------------------------//
struct SFyp{};

namespace ns
    {
        template <typename T2>
        void foo(SFyp fyp, T2 v2)
            {std::cout << "desired overload";}
    }
//------------------------------------------------------//
template <typename T1, typename T2>
void baz(T1 v1, T2 v2)
    { ns::foo(v1, v2); }


template <typename T1>
struct SZug
    {
        template <typename T2>
        void zug(T2 v2)
            {
                T1 v1;
                baz(v1, v2);
            }
    };



int main()
    {
        SZug<SFyp> z;
        z.zug(1);
    }
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/NRFkTcB2dT)

Comment: @xaxazak The simplest way to fix this is simply provide a definition for the primary function template so that qualified-lookup suffices. [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/NYTxphAxd). I've also added this in my answer as one way of solving the problem. And about the downvote, I can see the downvote(not in the timeline) but there is a way to see [downvote breakdown](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user).

Comment: Is there a way to fix it to use the desired overload?

Comment: Odd, I can't click the score to see the breakdown. Maybe a browser/OS/addon issue.

Comment: @xaxazak Once you'll reach `1000` SO reputation points you'll be able to click on that label and see the breakdown. The same is written [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) as *"Milestone privilege awarded at 1,000 reputation "*

Comment: @xaxazak Yes, there is a solution. See this [working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Q99atXuFp). In the above [linked demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Q99atXuFp) I've placed 3 comments so that you can easily spot what changes i've made. It calls the your desired overload as you expect. I've added the same at the end of my answer.

Comment: @xaxazak See the [complete working solution](https://onlinegdb.com/Q99atXuFp) at the end of my updated answer which will solve your issue and call the desired overload.

Comment: Unfortunately, the earlier code (foo, baz, SZug) is meant to be fully independent of SFyp (their headers should be fully read before SFyp is met). From OP, "if I put SFyp and its foo overload before baz, it succeeds". But I'm looking for a modular solution.

Comment: I'm just reading the [Qualified Name Lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup), but I don't see any reason there why the overload isn't found as a qualified lookup.

Comment: @xaxazak Because you've put that `foo` overload after defining `baz`. If you were to put that `foo` overload before defining `baz` as i did [here](https://onlinegdb.com/5wUfPB-yb), your program would've worked. I am also adding this as method 2 of solving your problem. Again in this [linked demo](https://onlinegdb.com/5wUfPB-yb) i've put some comments so that you can see whereever i have made changes.

Comment: I found a modular solution, although imperfect. Instead of having foo as a function, have it as a template struct that has the function as a static member. It seems baz can now find a later-defined qualified struct specialization even if it can't find a later-defined qualified overload.

Comment: @xaxazak I see. Anyways i've provided other solutions(3) so that now you've 4 solutions(including yours). Btw the solution that you mentioned works because specialization don't take part in overload resolution. There are many other things that are going on, but i think there is no need to explain everything in one post. Perhaps a new separate question will address that. Choose the solution(among the 4) that best fits your requirements.

Comment: Using specialization keeps it modular, which is essential. But I'll accept your answer for the good explanation, tyvm. I'm currently struggling with the raw spec to understand the convolutions of template name lookup, wish me luck :)