# first friend function template declaration is visible through `using namespace` but not through qualified name lookup

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, friend, argument-dependent-lookup

I have the following code I compile with C++11.
This code is a simplification of a real world usage.

```cpp
namespace bar {
template<int M = 10>
struct S {
    template<int N = M*2>
    friend int foo(S) { 
        return N-M; 
    }
};

template<int M, int N>
int foo(S<M>);

} /* end of bar */

int main() {
    bar::S<> s;
    /* OK    { using namespace bar; return foo<42>(s) + foo<>(s); } // */
    /* NOK   { return foo<42>(s) + foo<>(s); } // */
    /* NOK   { using namespace bar; return bar::foo<42>(s) + bar::foo<>(s); } // */
    /* NOK */{ return bar::foo<42>(s) + bar::foo<>(s); } // */
}
```

My question is: **Why does it compile with `using namespace bar;` with unqualified name lookup (see line with `/* OK` )?** While it does [not compile](https://godbolt.org/z/dWeh66cqs) in the variant using qualified name lookup (`bar::foo<>()`) or unqualified name lookup without `using namespace` (see lines with `/* NOK` )?

Comment: Because [ADL is for looking up **unqualified names**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74039755/namespace-usage-is-preventing-template-instantiation-of-overload)

Comment: @JasonLiam `return foo<42>(s) + foo<>(s);` is using unqualified names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The namespace `bar` contains declarations for different template functions called `foo`.

One is `template<int M, int N> int foo(S<M>);` declared at the end, and there is one for each `S<M>` declared as friend functions.

A friend function can only be found via ADL. So when you have `bar::foo<42>(s)`, you could only possibly be calling the free function (Where `42` is the value of `M` and `N` can't be deduced, so it doesn't compile).

[Prior to C++20](https://wg21.link/P0846R0), `foo<42>(s)` would be interpreted as `foo < 42 > (s)` (`(foo < 42) > s` with equivalent bracketing), since the `<` is not interpreted as a template head because lookup for `foo` doesn't find a template.

When you add `using namespace bar;`, lookup for `foo` finds the template function, so `foo<42>(s)` gets parsed as a templated function call. This eventually picks the friend function found via ADL during overload resolution.

This is fixed by adding a function template `foo` in the global namespace:

```cpp
// Only for ADL purposes so `foo` is parsed as a template
template<typename> void foo() = delete;

int main() {
    bar::S<> s;
    return foo<42>(s) + foo<>(s);
}
```